# linux 3.17 supports hotplug of thunderbolt of non-chained thunderbolt devices -- what is this?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Linux 3.17 has a [commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=16603153666d22df544ae9f9b3764fd18da28eeb&context=4&ignorews=0&ss=0) which supports hotplug of thunderbolt of non-chained thunderbolt devices. But what does "non-chained thunderbolt devices" mean? Is a thunderbolt to ethernet adapter a chained or non-chained device? How about a thunderbolt to display port adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Apple's promo page](https://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/) for info about Thunderbolt. It also describes how you can chain devices together instead of needing a hub or similar. My impression is that hot-plugging such daisy-chained devices are what are *not* supported by the linux commit; only single devices, whatever type they are.

Answer (score 2):

[Thunderbolt 3](https://www.anandtech.com/show/9331/intel-announces-thunderbolt-3) is a beast of a protocol and hardware solution. In Linux, there is some support for Apple devices but nothing very generic currently, as I understand. For instance with kernel 4.9 (Debian 9) with the Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 docking station and Lenovo Thinkpad T470 everything worked if I booted while attached to the dock. Suspend/ resume would not work, just the power and the display would come online. With [kernel 4.13](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.13#head-4743fcfb712d1a13f948b9877fc7c6fecb9e3d8d) I can reliably suspend/ resume with everything coming back online. I cannot hot-plug though.

BTW the original [Thunderbolt](https://www.anandtech.com/show/4194/intels-codename-lightpeak-launches-as-thunderbolt) is really relevant only on Apple hardware from what I know. Thunderbolt 2 got deployed more widely on Dell and Lenovo hardware in addition to Apples.

Thunderbolt should work as DisplayPort (and in case of Thunderbolt 3 as charger) pretty much all the time. The switch to "Thunderbolt alternative mode" should be easy enough to be supported as one of the first things.

Thunderbolt also allows for [networking](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1710.0/00406.html), which should be present in all major operating systems including [Linux kernel 4.15+](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5bbcc0f595fadb4cac0eddc4401035ec0bd95b09) shortly.